# Port forwarding not working on portable router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I have a portable router, namely a JioFi 3, currently very common in India. It runs on a Jio 4G LTE sim and is kind of a portable wifi hotspot type thing.

Now I installed tunngle on my PC and it requires me to forward the port 11155 to my PC. Fair enough, the router config page has an option to set up port forwarding and UPnP. Firstly, I enabled UPnP but that didn't work with tunngle. So I disabled UPnP and instead, manually forwarded the port to my PC. I did use my internal IP, the port number is correct, the protocol is correct, basically everything is correct. I then saved the settings and the router refreshed. That's it.

However, the port still isn't open. Tunngle still can't access the port, I tried checking whether the port was open or not using some port forward software. I tried 2 of them and both reported that the port was in fact, closed. I tried opening other ports(1000 on TCP) as well, but that also didn't work.

My router has no option for port triggering or something. I am attaching a screenshot of my current router settings.

Windows Firewall was disabled the entire time.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the LTE network has a firewall that blocks firewall unestablished connections?

Comment: Furthermore, many carriers don't give their customers individual external IPs, instead, multiple users appear as the same public IP on the internet. That makes incoming connections to these IPs impossible.

Comment: @LukeLR So what's the point? My ISP isn't allowing me to open the ports? Then why give an entire menu dedicated to UPnP and Port forwarding settings??

Comment: I also have same issue, after reading it looks like Jio network accessed via JioFi is behind NAT, as WAN IP seen in router settings is like 10.x.x.x while external IP checked via google is like 47.x.x.x

More info here https://broadbandforum.co/threads/reliance-jiofiber-port-forwarding-not-supported.160941/

Can try contacting customer support.

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP does NAT between its public IP (157.50.xx.xx) and the ISP internal private IP (10.89.xx.xx) also known as PIP.

The router you are using (JioFi, or whatever) hasn't got anything to do with this at all, the things will remain same even if you change your router/device. The ISP is controlling the NAT may be they are doing it to avoid misuse

Other options are renting a server with a public IP somewhere. Or using IPv6, if your ISP doesn't NAT this (some do).